# Probability of a dice

Tags: probability

Q: a fair dice is rolled 5 times. Find the probability that a score of 6 is recorded for exactly 2 of the rolls of the dice.

5 rolls seems too much to do a tree-diagram or permetations. I think the answer is something to do with nCr but I never understand why that is.

Could you use the binomial distribution?

Comment: Yes, the binomial distribution is the way to go.  You only care about two outcomes:  $6$ or non-$6$.

Comment: "*I think the answer is something to do with $~_nC_r$ but I never understand why that is*"  The binomial coefficient that appears in the binomial distribution comes about to describe the number of different orders that we could have had a success vs non-success.  The [wiki page for binomial distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) should have more information.

Comment: Dice is plural; singular is die

Comment: Is the question for roll pair of dice and the sum is $6$ for $2$ of the $5$ rolls?

Answer (score 1):

$^nC_r$ counts the ways to select $r$ elements from a set of $n$.

You wish to count arrangements of dice which two show `6` and three do not.   So that is the ways to select two places from five.

You also wish to evaluate the probability that any particular arrangement occurs.

Multiply the result.

> Could you use the binomial distribution?

Yes.

> $${^5C_2}\cdot{\tfrac{5^3}{6^5}}$$

Comment: A typo, you accidentally used $n=6$ rather than $n=5$.

Comment: Opps, yes.  @JMoravitz thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the binomial distribution counts the number of success in $n$ independent trials.

Here 'success' is the die shows a 6, this has $p=1/6$, a 'failure' is the die does not show a 6 and this has probability $1-p=5/6$, and there are $n=5$ trials.

Using probabilities from the binomial distribution $B(n,p)$
$$
P(X=2) = \, ^5C_2 \left(\frac{1}{6} \right)^2\left(\frac{5}{6} \right)^3 
$$